# How to wait for pyinstaller exe to complete in batch file

Tags: python, windows, selenium, batch-file, pyinstaller

I used [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) to convert my Python script to a .exe file.

The command I used was `pyinstaller --onefile QlikView.py`

I'm trying to create a batch file that runs QlikView.exe which gets an Excel sheet using the Selenium scraper and waits until it finishes. Then the batch file runs xls_to_csv.exe. However, the batch file exits immediately rather than waiting for the exe files to complete.

My batch file currently looks like this:

```
start /wait QlikView.exe
start /wait xls_to_csv.exe
```

According to [this page](https://serverfault.com/questions/245393/how-do-you-wait-for-an-exe-to-complete-in-batch-file):

> Either calling the exe directly from the batch file, or using start /wait will work but there is a caveat.
>
> If the exe you call then creates other process, such as calling another exe, and then exits the batch file will continue processing after the called exe has terminated, as it has no knowledge of other processes started by it.
>
> In your case this is a real problem because installers normally extract files from some form of compressed container, which may be embedded in the exe itself, then fire off one of the extracted files and exit. Some installers provide command line parameters which tell the original exe not to exit until the entire installation is complete, so that's something you may want to investigate. Other than that, there's no real way around this with batch files alone and would take a programmatic solution to solve.

So how do I get around this? Is there something I change with pyinstaller?